# Brush as DependencyProperty = Auto Freeze?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a brush defined in Xaml:

```
<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="MyCoolBrush" MappingMode="Absolute" RadiusX="70" RadiusY="70">
    <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.6" />
    </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</RadialGradientBrush>
```

I then have a DependencyProperty:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCoolBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyCoolBrush), typeof(Brush),
        typeof(MyCoolClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetDefaultCoolBrush()));
```

And GetDefaultCoolBrush looks like:

```
    private static Brush GetDefaultCoolBrush()
    {
        Brush brush = Application.Current.TryFindResource("MyCoolBrush") as Brush;

        if (brush == null)
            return null;

        return brush.Clone();
    }
```

I can understand TryFindResource returning a frozen brush since its defined in Xaml, so thus, I'm returning a Clone() of it.

Problem is, when I try do stuff to MyCoolBrush (through the DP) I get an exception saying its read only. If I try to modify the return value of GetDefaultCoolBrush() directly it works fine.

Why does setting the brush to a DP freeze it? Is that expected? I guess at some level if somebody sets the DP to Black, it makes sense to not be able to change it to Green for example, why not just pass in a new brush? But GradialRadientBrushes() are kind of expensive to set up, aren't they? Really, what I want to do is move the brush around, so I don't want to keep re-creating it, I just want to update the center point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding this is because the freezable design is tightly coupled to the DependencyObject infrastructure that behaves similar to the resource system for the same reasons.

When defining FrameworkElements (or DependencyObjects) like Brushes, Templates or Styles in XAML, e.g. App.xaml, they are static to the application but not part of any visual tree until instantiation. To be able to pass them around they will be sealed (to unhook them from the Dispatcher system) which causes Freezable types to freeze. The same applies to the DependencyProperty when setting the default value (via PropertyMetadata). This default value is static to the application. So the underlying dependency system has to seal this static values to be able to pass them around between the individual instances in order to serve as the default value. When you set the DependecyProperty after class initialization (e.g. after `Loaded` was raised) the actual instance values are no longer frozen because they are coupled to this particular instance.

Here is a snippet from the Freezable.cs. When DependencyProperty calls DependencyObject.Seal() on a freezable an override of ISealable.Seal() is invoked that causes the instance to freeze:

```
/// <summary>
/// Seal this freezable
/// </summary>
void ISealable.Seal()
{
    Freeze();
 }
```

DependencyProperty.Register() will invoke its internal method RegisterCommon() which validates the default value by calling ValidateMetadataDefaultValue() which calls ValidateDefaultValueCommon(). This method, defined in DependencyProperty.cs, finally seales the default value:

```
 private static void ValidateDefaultValueCommon(
        object defaultValue,
        Type propertyType,
        string propertyName,
        ValidateValueCallback validateValueCallback,
        bool checkThreadAffinity)
    {
        // Ensure default value is the correct type
        if (!IsValidType(defaultValue, propertyType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(SR.Get(SRID.DefaultValuePropertyTypeMismatch, propertyName));
        }

        // An Expression used as default value won't behave as expected since
        //  it doesn't get evaluated.  We explicitly fail it here.
        if (defaultValue is Expression )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(SR.Get(SRID.DefaultValueMayNotBeExpression));
        }

        if (checkThreadAffinity)
        {
            // If the default value is a DispatcherObject with thread affinity
            // we cannot accept it as a default value. If it implements ISealable
            // we attempt to seal it; if not we throw  an exception. Types not
            // deriving from DispatcherObject are allowed - it is up to the user to
            // make any custom types free-threaded.

            DispatcherObject dispatcherObject = defaultValue as DispatcherObject;

            if (dispatcherObject != null && dispatcherObject.Dispatcher != null)
            {
                // Try to make the DispatcherObject free-threaded if it's an
                // ISealable.

                ISealable valueAsISealable = dispatcherObject as ISealable;

                if (valueAsISealable != null && valueAsISealable.CanSeal)
                {
                    Invariant.Assert (!valueAsISealable.IsSealed,
                           "A Sealed ISealable must not have dispatcher affinity");

                    valueAsISealable.Seal();

                    Invariant.Assert(dispatcherObject.Dispatcher == null,
                        "ISealable.Seal() failed after ISealable.CanSeal returned true");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(SR.Get(SRID.DefaultValueMustBeFreeThreaded, propertyName));
                }
            }
        }
```

In the code above you find the comment that states:

> If the default value is a DispatcherObject with thread affinity
>               we cannot accept it as a default value. If it implements ISealable
>               we attempt to seal it; if not we throw  an exception. Types not
>               deriving from DispatcherObject are allowed - it is up to the user to
>               make any custom types free-threaded.

Summary: Types like Style, FrameworkTemplate, Brushes or Freezable (e.g. Brush) do all implement ISealable, whereas the implementation provided by Freezable makes a call to Freeze(). Setting the **default value** of a DependencyProperty causes ISealable.Seal() to be invoked by the DependencyProperty.
Because of this your cloned (which sets IsFrozen to false) will get frozen again when assigned to the PropertyMetadata as the default value. Since you are operating on this default value, you will get an exception when modifying it.